# How to split a string into an array by html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to split a string that contains text inside p tags into an array for each set of tags

```
"<p>Solecum am, sitio quis sa doluptatem harum fugiaturi bea earum</p><p>sum quamus excearum ilitinverum et quid quiandelis ad qui remporum sus</p><p>ullant ma quas eaque parum quae venditeces sinctur aut eum quo odipsumet odEquias endis el il idit atector.</p>"
```

From what I have read regular expressions are a no go with HTML? If someone could provide some insight / a solution that would be much appreciated

Comment: convert to **DOM**, then loop the children nodes.

Comment: *I am trying to...* <-- So what have you tried?

Comment: Ok I have deleted my answer.

Comment: I think it's a fair question to ask for clarification on contradicting answers to a commonly asked question - at no point did I ask write this code for me I am just looking for a bit of direction

Comment: You could get some direction via a simple Google search. We expect that you'll do that research before posting here. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simple text you can split in this way:

```js
s = "<p>Solecum am, sitio quis sa doluptatem harum fugiaturi bea earum</p><p>sum quamus excearum ilitinverum et quid quiandelis ad qui remporum sus</p><p>ullant ma quas eaque parum quae venditeces sinctur aut eum quo odipsumet odEquias endis el il idit atector.</p>";

res = s.split(/<p>/);
for (i=1;i<res.length;i++)res[i-1]="<p>"+res[i];
res.pop(-1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: We tend not to answer poor questions where the OP has not made any attempt at solving the problem themselves first as it just attracts more poor questions.